# Is it possible to determine the http request method (POST/GET) using a variable?

Tags: variables, jmeter

I am using a csv file as the basis for my requests. The thing is, I have some GET requests and some POST requests. Is there a way to use the same http request element for both request types where the method will be determined by the variable from the csv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most direct solution for this would be to have two requests in the test plan, one a GET and one a POST.  This does not quite satisfy your requirement to have it use the SAME request element, but it is probably the best solution.

Nest each of those inside their own IF controllers that reads a value from the CSV.

For example lets say the csv is the following:
http_method,host,path,params...

The first IF could be:

```
"${http_method}" == "GET"
```

Then the next:

```
"${http_method}" == "POST"
```

Each line from the CSV would only evaluate true to one of the statements, and then make the correct POST or GET call.

Answer (score 6):

This is really simple using Beanshell Preprocessor.

Add a Beanshell preprocessor for your existing HTTP request. Lets assume the default HTTP method is `GET`.

Now lets change it to POST whenever the csv variable 'method' is 'POST'

```
if(vars.get("method").equalsIgnoreCase("POST")){
     sampler.setMethod("POST");  //this will change current sampler's http method from GET to POST. 
}
```

Comment: There's a typo in the mentioned code, in the section 'equalsIngoreCase', spelling of Ignore need to be corrected. Otherwise works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1. Use [HTTP Raw Request](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/) available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/)
2. Write your custom logic in Java. See "How to Write a Custom AJAX Request Sampler" chapter of [How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter) for idea on how this could be done.